# Which hashing algorithm is best for HMAC

Tags: hash, .net-4.5

Which hashing algorithm is best for HMAC applications? "Best" is a combination of strength and availability of libraries to generate a hash.

The server-side stack is all Microsoft, specifically .NET 4.5. The clients are potentially any client out there but likely .NET also.

Answer (score 3):

So HMAC is pretty standard, and available in [Java](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/crypto/Mac.html), [.NET](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.hmac.aspx), [PHP](http://php.net/manual/en/function.hash-hmac.php). From a quick look at the Java and PHP docs if the language supports a hashing algorithm if appears to support using it in HMAC generation. Given that, the strongest is going to be SHA512.

You should also look at the NIST guidelines and [checked algorithms](http://csrc.nist.gov/groups/STM/cavp/documents/mac/hmacval.html).